# What does it mean that the distribution of a variable is well-defined?

Tags: terminology, normal-distribution, distribution-theory, cryptography, lattices-in-lie-groups

In the proof of a lemma in a paper, the authors say "Observe the distribution of $\vec{d}$ is well-defined." What does it mean mathematically?

Here is the picture of the notation, lemma, and its proof.

**Reference**: [Shuichi Katsumata, Shota Yamada. "Partitioning via Non-Linear Polynomial Functions: More Compact IBEs from Ideal Lattices and Bilinear Map", in Asiacrypt 2017, [IACR 2017/843](https://eprint.iacr.org/2016/843)]

---

[image]

---

Comment: Generally, *well-defined* refers to a formula or process that appears to depend on some choice, but in actuality doesn't. For example, the function $f:\mathbb{Q} \to \mathbb{Q}$, defined by  
$$
f\Bigl(\frac{a}{b}\Bigr) = \frac{a^2+b^2}{ab}
$$ 
is well defined, as it's just $f(x) = x + \frac1x$ in disguise. However, something like 
$$
f\Bigl(\frac{a}{b}\Bigr) = a + b
$$ 
is not, as it depends on the particular representation of the input.